# Integer solutions of $x^n+y^n=z^n+w^n $ [$(n,2,2)$ Lander, Parkin, Selfridge]

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I am wondering if integers of the form

$x^n\:+y^n\:=z^n\:+w^n$

have a solution if none of $x,\:y,\:z,\:or\:w$ are equal.

Comment: Isn't this a generalisation of FLT?

Comment: I don't actually know, that is why I am asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's always the taxicab identity:
$$ 12^3+1^3 = 10^3+9^3 $$

It is not known whether examples exist for all exponents. For fourth powers there is
$$ 133^4 + 134^4 = 158^4 + 59^4 $$
but even for fifth powers no example is known (nor a proof that there *are* no examples).  See the [Lander, Parkin, Selfridge conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lander,_Parkin,_and_Selfridge_conjecture). This is the special case $(n,2,2)$.

Comment: Oh, Thank you! Could you explain the taxicab identity a little bit?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_number also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_taxicab_number